# Python QTWebEngine page doesn't load with custom cookie

Tags: python, qt, session-cookies, qtwebengine

I want the user to input an account name so I can look for a matching token on storage.
If the token exists I want to load a webview with the set cookie. This will aid in fast login when the user has multiple accounts.
The cookie is getting set as def on_cookie_added is printing the token, but the page doesn't load with the user logged in.

```
Name: ACCESS_INFO
Value: 00000000%xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
The 0s are the fixed user Id from Twitch, the x are generated characters generated by Stream Raiders. From the tokens I checked, it always has 111 characters in total
Domain: .www.streamraiders.com
Path: /
Expires: Time in ISO 8601 
Size: 122
HttpOnly: True
Secure: True
SameSite: Lax
Priority: Medium
```

Here's the code, very simple, gets user input and loads the  webview. That is working properly.

```
import time
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QDateTime
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkCookie
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from utils import constants
from utils.settings import open_file

name = input("Please insert the account name you want to access: ")
accounts = open_file(constants.py_accounts)
ACCESS_INFO = None

for account in accounts:
    if account["name"] == name:
        ACCESS_INFO = account["token"]
        break
else:
    print("Please insert the account you would like to access.")
    sys.exit()

app = QApplication([])

view = QWebEngineView()
page = QWebEnginePage()


store = page.profile().cookieStore()

store.deleteAllCookies()

cookie = QNetworkCookie()
cookie.setName(b"ACCESS_INFO")
cookie.setValue(ACCESS_INFO.encode("utf-8"))
cookie.setDomain(".www.streamraiders.com")
cookie.setPath("/")
expiration_date = QDateTime.currentDateTime().addDays(5)
cookie.setExpirationDate(expiration_date)
cookie.setHttpOnly(True)
cookie.setSecure(True)

store.setCookie(cookie, QUrl("https://www.streamraiders.com"))

view.setPage(page)

def on_cookie_added(cookie):
    cookie_name = cookie.name().data().decode()
    cookie_value = cookie.value().data().decode()
    if cookie_name == "ACCESS_INFO":
        print(cookie_value)
        time.sleep(5)
        view.setUrl(view.url())

store.cookieAdded.connect(on_cookie_added)

url = QUrl("https://www.streamraiders.com")
view.setUrl(url)

view.show()
app.exec_()
```

I've already tried type the domain in different ways such as without the leading dot, with https, without the expiration date. I've already tried passing only the name and the value. Nothing worked.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Calling `setUrl()` with the same url is completely pointless. You should at least use `reload()`. And you should also **not** use blocking functions like `time.sleep()` in the main UI thread; if you want to delay a function call, use `QTimer.singleShot()`.

Comment: I already did view.reload() before and didn't work. Did it again alongside QTimer.singleShot(), didn't work either. My idea here was to reload the page after the cookie is set. But it sleeps, reloads and the cookie is gone.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is an insufficient explanation. *What* doesn't work? Does the page reload or not? If the the reload *does* work, but the user is not logged, then either the cookie isn't properly set, or the server/page doesn't accept it as valid for that purpose.

Comment: It reloaded the page, but without the custom cookies. Anyways, case closed, the code is fine, it's the way the server handles the tokens (which is outside my control). Fresh tokens work, old tokens don't which I managed to reproduce both manually and with the script. This left me flabbergasted because these "invalid" tokens aren't allowing the user to log in using the browser session, but my app is using these same tokens perfectly fine to perform some automated http requests. Regardless, I added a note for the user to generate fresh tokens if they aren't working on the browser.

Comment: Note that in your token above you only showed us the initial zeroes, the following values are most certainly set from the server with some encryption in order to properly authenticate the user. It isn't clear if those `x` you used are placeholders or you actually did use `x`; in that case, it's obviously invalid: the server uses encrypted values in order to properly ensure that the authentication is valid (possibly with a server side expiration and a checksum), it obviously isn't sufficient to just set the user name in the cookie, otherwise there would be a *huge* security problem there.

Comment: Those were placeholders. Apparently they remain valid until a new legitimate log in is performed. Regardless, we learn something new everyday. But the fact that the old ones can still somehow be used is strange.

Comment: Note that if you tried to use those same values with different user names, it would be invalid anyway.

Comment: Why not delete the question? The question in its current state is not useful to others.